# This expression is not callable, Type 'UserService' has no call signatures

Tags: angular, typescript

Good day,

After searching for this error and found some similar scenarios, I can't relate the answers to my problem (newbie mistakes).
I have the error described in the title when I trying to call for a function located in `user.service.ts` while I'm trying to use it in my add-new-message component

So this is the `user.service.ts`

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {GLOBAL} from './global';
import {User} from '../models/user';

@Injectable()
export class UserService{
public url:String;
public identity;
public token;
public stats;
public user;

constructor(public _http: HttpClient){
    this.url =GLOBAL.url;
    
}

getIdentity(){
    let identity = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('identity'));

    if(identity != 'undefined'){
        this.identity = identity;
    }else{
        this.identity= null;
    }

    return this.identity;
}

getToken(){
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if(token != "undefined"){
        this.token = token;
    }else {
        this.token = null;
    }

    return this.token;
}
```

And this is my `add.component.ts`

```
import {Component, OnInit, DoCheck} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
import {Follow} from '../../../models/follow';
import {Message} from '../../../models/message';
import {MessageService} from '../../../services/message.service';
import {FollowService} from '../../../services/follow.service';
import {User} from '../../../models/user';
import {UserService} from '../../../services/user.service';
import {GLOBAL} from '../../../services/global';


@Component({
selector: 'add',
templateUrl: './add.component.html',
providers: [
FollowService, MessageService, UserService
]
})

export class AddComponent implements OnInit {
public title: string;
public message: Message;
public identity;
public token;
public url: string;
public status: string;
public follows;


constructor(

    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router,
    private _followService: FollowService,
    private _messageService: MessageService,
    private _userService: UserService

    ){
    this.title = 'New message';
    this.message = new Message('','','','',this.identity._id,'');
    this.identity = this._userService().getIdentity();
    this.token = this._userService().getToken();
    this.url = GLOBAL.url;
}

ngOnInit(){
console.log('add.component loaded');
}

}
```

so both `this.identity = this._userService().getIdentity();` and `this.token = this._userService().getToken();` are throwing me the same error

```
This expression is not callable.
Type 'UserService' has no call signatures.

41   this.identity = this._userService().getIdentity();
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You no need to call the _userService as a function/method, change to this

```
this.identity = this._userService.getIdentity();
this.token = this._userService.getToken();
```